# Jest: modulePaths and/or moduleDirectories in configuration still don't make imported modules present

Tags: reactjs, meteor, module, jestjs

I am trying to write some tests for my React components and am having a bit of trouble with module imports. My **jest.config.js** file is located in the root of my project. I have roots, modulePaths, and moduleDirectories all in my configuration, and have tried a few things I have read from examples and tutorials. No matter what I do though I keep getting this issue

```
Cannot find module '/path/to/moduleA' from '/path/to/moduleB/which/imports/moduleA
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and have tried to do my due dilligence, reading the Jest documentation and looking around for tutorials articles quite some time without luck. I might be totally misunderstanding how module loading works in Jest as well.

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // All imported modules in your tests should be mocked automatically
  automock: false,

  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: "node",

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],

  roots: [
    "<rootDir>",
  ],

  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>",
    "/path/to/moduleA"
  ],

  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules",
    "/path/to/moduleA"
  ],
};
```

Comment: You're specifying absolute paths in your example; that could be the problem here.

Comment: Tell us more information about your app folder structure